# C++ Create Template in Class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

Hi I tried to create a List Class.
But in order to have a variation of list class, I am using template to store value in item variable.

Below is in "List.h"

```
template <class ListItemType>
    class List
    {
        public:
            .........
            .........

        private:
            struct ListNode
            {
                ListItemType item;
                ListNode    *next; 
            };

        int size; 
        ListNode *head;
        ListNode *find(int index) const;
    };
```

Then how do I create the implementation of "ListNode *find(int index) const" function in List.cpp?

I tried to use

```
template <class ListItemType>
    List<ListItemType>::ListNode *List<ListItemType>::find(int index) const
    {
        ........
    }
```

But there is an error saying "error: need 'typename' before 'List::ListNode' because 'List' is a dependent scope"

Do you know how do I implement "ListNode *find(int index) const" in List.cpp?

This is my first time using template, I am a bit confuse.
Thanks

Comment: The error is quite clear (not usually the case with templates). You need `typename List<ListItemType>::ListNode `.

Comment: @juanchopanza oke thanks, and let say I declare the list as a pointer, assign it to an instance, and I want that template to have integer value. And how do I do that?

Comment: Why would you want a pointer? Just create an object: `List<int> my_list;`

Comment: @juanchopanza ok. and why, when I tried to declare it in another class (List<int> my_list;) i created. When that class constructor is called there is an error saying "Undefined reference to 'List<int>::List()'"

Comment: That is because the linker cannot find the implementation of `List`'s default constructor. Make sure all the implementations are in the header file.

Comment: @juanchopanza when we declare the implementation in header files, do i need to also specify template or typename or just simply "List();"?

Comment: @IhsanMuhammad if its inside the class decl, just `List() { ...code...}` will be adequate. If it is outside the class decl, then you need to fully qualify it, including the template characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ListNode` is a name of a type within your templated class you need to write:

```
typename List<ListItemType>::ListNode
```

Also, the implementation of your template probably needs to be visible to everyone. I wouldn't put it into a separate .cpp file.